# How do I load my all JPEG images from a folder to a R variable?

Tags: r, image, jpeg

I want all image in a variable in R from a "train" folder. There are 18539 images and their names are (0.jpg, 1.jpg,...... 18539.jpg).

When I had fewer images I used to do in this way. Is there a more efficient way when we have many images?

```r
Img <- c("train/0.jpg","train/1.jpg.........")
trainImg <- []
for (i in 1:18) 
{
  trainImg[[i]] <- readImage(Img[i])
}
```

I want to load all the images even when we have no idea how many images a folder has. The function should load all the images in a folder and store them in a list.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `lapply`: `myImageList <- lapply(Img, readImage)` should return a list of images if the Img vector is set up properly.

Comment: Yes, but before that, I need to store their names in a vector then load the image by numbering. Is there any way I can store them without specifying their names? Like which I did in an `Img` variable.

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are asking, but maybe you want `dir`: `img <- dir(full.names=TRUE)`.

Comment: the way I'm doing, I can access image by this `print(trainImg[[1]])` it may help you know what I want. Now I have many images in a folder so I can't store them like this `Img <- c("train/0.jpg","train/1.jpg.........")`. So is there any way I can store all my images and can access them like this in a script `print(trainImg[[1]])`

Comment: `train` is a name of folder and images name are like this `0.jpg, 1.jpg,...... 18539.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

To automate the creation of the your filenames, try something like:

```
 filenames<-paste0("train/", 0:18539, ".jpg")
```

This will create the list:

```
[1] "train/0.jpg"  "train/1.jpg"  "train/2.jpg"  "train/3.jpg" ....
```

You can then pass this vector to lapply function as recommended in the comments.

If you want a list of files in your directory, then use `list.files` function.

```
 filenames<-list.files("train/", pattern=".jpg")
```

Comment: while doing this `paste0("train/", 0:18539, ".jpg")` I'm getting _train/_ in a image file name. I was using _train/_ for setting the directory so that it will pick images from the train name folder.

Comment: Avoid potential bugs by using `list.files` and get the names of the files that are there.

Comment: @AdarshPawar, Please see the edits above, I think this answers your question.